# FlutterBarcodeScanner failed to navigate after successfully scanned QR Code

Tags: flutter

Using the following package with latest flutter.

```
flutter_barcode_scanner: any
```

Sample code:

```
var qr = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode("#ff6666", "Cancel", true, ScanMode.QR);
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyAnotherPage()));
```

The navigator works if I comment out the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Holy grail, I don't know why, but in this case I have to change to:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) { return MyAnotherPage(); }));
```

I don't know why lambda expression doesn't work here. Wasted more than 2 days in this problem.